# Redemption: RDOMail accessing attachments and moving mail

Tags: plugins, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am trying to access the attachments for an RDOMail object. When I either search for a specific item using LINQ or just try and iterate through the list with a foreach it freezes outlook and throws no exception.
Also when I try and move the RDOMail to another folder it freezes outlook and throws no exception.

I can accomplish both these things just using the Outlook.MailItem
Anyone have any ideas?

```
void store_OnNewMail(string entryId)
{
   RDOMail mail = _store.GetMessageFromID(entryId);

   RDOAttachment protocolAttachment = mail.Attachments.Cast<RDOAttachment>().SingleOrDefault(attach => attach.FileName == "protocol.id");

   mail.Move(_hiddenDeliveryTrustFolder);
}
```

Comment: I sent the debug version of Redemption to your private email address...

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I work with Dave and was testing this myself. I noticed that I can use Redemption to get a message that's already in the store `_store.GetMessageFromID(inbox.Items[1].EntryID);`, but if I try to use the same method from the context of the `OnNewMail` event to retrieve an incoming message Outlook simply hangs and must be shut down via task manager. Do you mind sending me the debug dll's as well? Dave is out for the rest of the week

Comment: I found that if get the message from a new thread it works. This is in Outlook 2007.

Comment: Dave actually sent me the LOG file, below is my reply. The fact that this is an IMAP4 store is the key here IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the IMAP4 message available at the time of the NewMail event is just an envelope message (header only, no body or attachments). When you access the attachments, IMAP4 provider attempts to connect to the IMAP4 server to retrieve the data, but the call is blocked because of a critical section signaled before the event is raised.
Try to bypass the IMAP4 provider level by

```
 RDOStore unwrappedStore = rSession.Stores.UnwarpStore(_store);
 RDOMail mail = unwrappedStore.GetMessageFromID(entryId);
```

You can also try to save the message entry id in a variable and start a timer (use the one from the Forms namespace). When the timer event fires (you will be out of the newMail event by then), you can open the message and process it.